# PHP Class extending TCPDF

Tags: php, oop, tcpdf, extend

TCPDF Example 002 shows custom Header/Footer methods in an extended class. It works fine.

I have a more general class hierarchy

**In one file**

```
Class Three extends Two{
  public function Header(){
    die;
  }
  public function Footer(){
    die;
  }
}
```

**In another file**

```
Class Two extends One{
  public function Header(){
    die;
  }
  public function Footer(){
    die;
  }
}
```

**In yet another file**

```
Class One extends TCPDF{
  public function Header(){
    die;
  }
  public function Footer(){
    die;
  }
}
```

Wherever (Class One, Two or Three) I place my functions `Header()` and `Footer()` they are not overriding the base methods in TCPDF.

Can someone tell me how method overriding is failing for me? The die statements are never reached and the base header is displayed so my overrides do not work.

Update:

get_declared_classes reveals that all classes are loaded and in the correct order.

```
[316] => String(5)  "TCPDF"
[317] => String(15)  "TCPDF_FONT_DATA"
[318] => String(11)  "TCPDF_FONTS"
[319] => String(12)  "TCPDF_COLORS"
[320] => String(12)  "TCPDF_IMAGES"
[321] => String(12)  "TCPDF_STATIC"
[322] => String(24)  "Drupal\pdf\One"
[323] => String(30)  "Drupal\pdf\Two"
[324] => String(38)  "Drupal\pdf\Three"
```

Comment: please show your `Header()` methods and also the code you are using to call them.

Answer (score 1):

I had this code

```
$pdf = new \TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

in

```
Class One extends \TCPDF
```

effectively having two instances of TCPDF!!.

All is wonderful again. For a while that is.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are extending a class that hasn't been loaded yet.  Reverse the order of your class definitions.

If you turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)` you should see some errors similar to:

> "Fatal error: Class 'Three' not found in path/to/file on line x"

So just reversing them should solve it:

```
include('TCPDF.php');

//In yet another file
Class One extends TCPDF
{
    public function Header()
    {
        die;
    }

    public function Footer()
    {
        die;
    }
}

//In another file
Class Two extends One
{
    public function Header()
    {
        die;
    }

    public function Footer()
    {
        die;
    }
}


//in one file
Class Three extends Two
{
    public function Header()
    {
        die;
    }

    public function Footer()
    {
        die;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your comment evades me.  I call new Three(). When AddPage() is called I wish Three::Header() to be called not TCPDF::Header(). I do not control the loading of parent classes!

Comment: Okay, do you see any errors when you turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Comment: No errors. The base (parent) header is displayed but not the custom (child) one.